# How can I get address information using latitude and longitude?

Tags: android, kotlin

I made [this](https://doctorcodetutorial.blogspot.com/2020/05/android-simplest-way-to-get-user.html) tutorial for get user's address and location but I got error when I changed AVD's location. When I didn't call `getCityName` function at `getLastLocation` function, I can get user's location but when I call it, it gave that error. How can I solve it?

it was give an error which was :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.slidework3, PID: 15792
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: grpc failed
        at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
        at com.example.slidework3.AdresPage.getCityName(AdresPage.kt:152)
        at com.example.slidework3.AdresPage.access$getCityName(AdresPage.kt:20)
        at com.example.slidework3.AdresPage$getLastLocation$1.onComplete(AdresPage.kt:66)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**Edit:**
I tried real device, location services working well I can get city name, street name etc. But in simulator it was give error again. I tried to change AVD's location after that it was going to crash. I believe solution is simple but I don't know how can I search this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try run the operation in a new Thread, and then if I need to update some UI view I'll do it on runOnUiThread.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address#java